# display the filenames with 4 or more characters using ls

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing, ls

How to display the filenames with 4 or more characters using the ls command

Answer (score 9):

Use wildcards (they're not regexps):

```
ls -A -d ????*
```

That's  4 "any characters" followed by "any number of any characters". `man ls`.

Comment: You say `man ls`, but what good will that do anyone? Globbing is performed by the shell; `ls` doesn't know about it and there's nothing about it in its manual.

Comment: Although I see the asker artificially required Ls, invoking Ls here is just useless and requires using `-d` flag to make Ls work more or less like a plain Printf at the end of the day. In other words, spawning no new external process, one may simply write `printf '%s\n' ????*` or `echo ????*`.

Comment: @Quasímodo `printf` works (though filenames having newlines might cause confusion), but with `echo` I get no newlines making it impossible to read the filenames. The advantage of `ls` is that it's designed to *display to the user* files in a directory in the most readable and unambiguous way. Personally, I don't think all of its design elements contribute to that end, but that is the intent. The commands you mention have different purposes and are less suited to this task.

Comment: I agree with marcelm. We should rather read `man bash` or indeed https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion - `man ls` will be of little help.

Comment: @waltinator - should it be ls -A -d ???* if he wants 4 or more characters? I’m not sure if the * mandates at least 1 character after the 4 wildcards in your answer? Or can the * be any number of characters *including zero* in which case your answer is perfect?

Comment: @will - that's a good question , it doesn't - * also matches ''.  So ???* matches foo - This is easily tested. Personally I would be piping ls -la  through grep, and what about links and folders?